# EOF error when reading from stdin - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm receiving the following error when I run this script and press CTR-D to end my input to the program:

**The Error:**

```
My-MacBook-Pro-2:python me$ python3 test.py 
>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    line = input(">> ")
EOFError
```

**The Script**

```
import sys

while(1):
    line = input("Say Something: ")
    print(line)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Has anything else changed in `test.py` vs what you copied and pasted? Because the Traceback as well as the output shows a completely different `input` command. I cannot replicate this error on my system. (I get `KeyboardInterrupt` as expected.)

Comment: Are you sure you're not sending a CTRL+D? That sends an EOF character to stdin, which would explain what you're seeing.

Comment: @dano I apologize, I mean to type CTRL+D. Yes, essentially my question is how do I handle EOF when reading stdin?

Answer (score 6):

This is not likely to help Apollo (besides, question is 4 years old), but this might help someone like myself.

I had this same issue and *without hitting a single key*, the same code would terminate immediately into EOFError. In my case, culprit was another script executed earlier in the same terminal, which had set stdin into non-blocking mode.

Should the cause be the same, this should help:

```
flag = fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdin.fileno(), fcntl.F_GETFL)
fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdin.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, flag & ~os.O_NONBLOCK)
```

I identified the offending Python script and made the correction. Other scripts with input() now work just fine after it.

Edit (plus couple of typos above):
This should let you see if STDIN is non-blocking mode:

```
import os
import sys
import fcntl
flag = fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdin.fileno(), fcntl.F_GETFL)
print(
    "STDIN is in {} mode"
    .format(
        ("blocking", "non-blocking")[
            int(flag & os.O_NONBLOCK == os.O_NONBLOCK)
        ]
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `input`, there's no need to send EOF to end your input; just press enter. `input` is designed to read until a newline character is sent.

If you're looking for a way to break out of the while loop, you could use CTRL+D, and just catch the `EOFError`:

```
try:
    while(1):
        line = input("Say Something: ")
        print(line)
except EOFError:
    pass
```